# Google Play - Whitelist of users?

Tags: android, google-play, b2b

I have just finished developing an app for a client which is to be used as a B2B procurement app. Given this is a corporate app, they do not want this to be publicly available to the masses. I have read up on private distribution channels, but from what I understand (correct me if I am wrong), this is only possible for users on the same domain - i.e. internal users.

This app is for our clients clients, meaning they will all have different domains.

I've seen some people recommending that the app just stay in beta and limit users by the beta group list. This seems like a really bad idea as that is designed for 'beta testing'.

1 - What options do I have to deploy the app to a set of users?

2 - The app is currently setup under our development company. If the above is possible, is there any way I can handover control of this whitelist to the client whilst still keeping us as the app owner/linked to our account?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have never really used this but : https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en

Comment: As I mentioned, it looks like this is only suitable for users on the same domain. This doesn't help.

Comment: Could you white-list based on device id? There are apps that let users find theirs e.g: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evozi.deviceid&hl=en You could add their device id to a whitelist and check their device against it when the app starts up

Comment: This would still mean the app is displayed publicly. I'm not trying to create a whitelist for a security measure, it's just not something the client wants displayed to the general public. Surely there is a way to limit this without putting hacks in place like this. Surely I haven't created the first b2b app

Comment: Did you figure this out? This is exactly my situation now and it's 2020.